# Curve fit equation not properly fitting curve

Tags: python

I am using this code to curve fit some data:

```
def extract_parameters(Ts, ts):
    def model(t, Ti, Ta, c):
        return (Ti - Ta)*math.e**(-t / c) + Ta
    popt, pcov = cf(model, Ts, ts, p0 = (10, 6, 7))
    Ti, Ta, c = popt
    maxx = max(Ts)
    xfine = np.linspace(0, maxx, 101)
    print "xfine: ", xfine
    yfitted = model(xfine, *popt)
    print "yfittted", yfitted
    pl.plot(Ts, ts, 'o', label = 'data point')
    pl.plot(xfine, yfitted, label = 'fit')
    pylab.legend()
    pylab.show()
    return Ti, Ta, c
```

When I enter:

```
 extract_parameters([1,2,3,4,5,6],[100,60,50,40,45,34])
```

I get a perfect fit

but when I enter:

```
extract_parameters([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[100,80,70,65,60,58,56])
```

I get this instead [image]

Can anyone see why? The curve fit changes drastically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optimizers like `curve_fit` try to find the optimal fit, but don't always succeed.
Notice that `extract_parameters([1,2,3,4,5,6],[100,60,50,40,45,34])` returns

```
(196.85292746741234, 38.185643828689777, 1.0537367332516778)
```

That means it started with an initial parameter guess of `p0 = (10, 6, 7)`
and found its way to quite a different location.

You can help the optimizer out by picking an initial guess which is closer to the optimal value. Simply by changing it to

```
p0 = (100, 6, 7)
```

allows

```
extract_parameters([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[100,80,70,65,60,58,56])
```

to find a better fit: `(131.71232607048836, 54.894539483338022, 1.8503931318517444)`.

[image]

Comment: Perfect that looks good. What does p0 actually do? What values is it guessing? Thanks.

Comment: `p0` is the initial guess for the parameters, `Ti, Ta, c`.